# Haskell Inferred Type Error

Tags: haskell, type-inference

I am new to Haskell and am curious why this is causing an error.

```
sumtest :: (Real a) => [a] -> a
sumtest [] = 0
sumtest (x:xs) = x + sumtest xs

avgFunction ::  (Integral a, Floating b) => [a] -> b
avgFunction a = sumtest a / length a
```

Error

```
ERROR file:code/test1.hs:114  - Inferred type is not general enough
*** Expression    : avgFunction
*** Expected type : (Integral a, Floating b) => [a] -> b
*** Inferred type : (Integral Int, Floating Int) => [Int] -> Int
```

----- Working Code Below Per Accepted Answer----

```
sumtest :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
sumtest [] = 0
sumtest (x:xs) = x + sumtest xs

avgFunction ::  (Integral a, Floating b) => [a] -> b
avgFunction a = fromIntegral (sumtest a) / fromIntegral (length a)
```

Comment: The signature of `avgFunction` suggests that you convert somewhere from `a` to `b`. Where is this supposed to happen? At the moment you don't do a conversion anywhere, hence the error. BTW, a conversion from a general `Num` isn't _possible_. How do you “convert” a complex number to a real one?

Comment: Please see edits - Yea i would like to take in integers and end up with potentially a decimal average.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The result of `sumtest a` has type `a`. We know this an `Integral` type. Hence a type that can *not* be divided...
- The result of `length a` has type `Int`. This is also an `Integral` type. (And possibly `a` is a different one.)

So you're trying to divide two numbers, both of which have types that *can not* be divided. Well, that can't work, can it?

Fortunately, you can convert numbers. Some languages actually do this implicitly (regularly leading to all kinds of havoc<sup>†</sup>), but not Haskell. Well, but it sure has *functions* to do it! [hoogle is your friend](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28Integral+a%2C+Floating+b%29+%3D%3E+a+-%3E+b):

```
avgFunction a = fromIntegral (sumtest a) / fromIntegral (length a)
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Admittedly, it *is* sometimes just annoying to have to convert every `length` to `Int` or `Double`. And some conservative implicit conversions, like Python does, sure don't seem *too* bad. But *any* kind of implicit conversion would not work with a Hindley-Milner type system like Haskell's.</sub>

---

On another note: these constraints are actually unnecessarily strong. The following is sufficient:

```
avgFunction ::  (Real a, Fractional b) => [a] -> b
avgFunction a = realToFrac (sumtest a) / realToFrac (length a)
```

This way, the function will also allow `Double` as the input, not just as the result. (And perhaps it's also easier to understand what's going on.)

Answer (score 0):

(This is really a comment/enhancement of [leftaroundabout's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36668188/1126841), but really needs more formatting than comments allow.)

---

The module `Data.Function` provides a function `on` which allows you to specify a function to apply to each of another function's arguments. In this case,

```
avgFunction a = (sumtest a) ./ (length a)
                where (./) = (/) `on` fromIntegral
```

It's actually a little longer, but it's arguably clearer in the sense that the locally defined `./` operator allows you to focus the algorithm by abstracting away the type-conversion boilerplate code.

---

And then there's also this fun little gem using `Control.Arrow`:

```
avgFunction = sum &&& length >>> uncurry ((/) `on` fromIntegral)
```

Comment: Note that this restricts the function signature to `[Int] -> b`.